# Conceptual Difference between $p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f})$ and $ p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{X},\mathbf{y})$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, gaussian-process

So the predictive distribution of the Gaussian process is provided as follows where $p(\mathbf{f} \lvert \mathbf{X},\mathbf{y})$ and $p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{X},\mathbf{y})$ is the predictive distribution, taken from [Martin Krasser  blog](http://krasserm.github.io/2018/03/19/gaussian-processes/)

$$
p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{X},\mathbf{y}) 
= \int{p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f})p(\mathbf{f} \lvert \mathbf{X},\mathbf{y})}\ d\mathbf{f} \\ 
= \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \boldsymbol{\mu}_*, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_*)$$

Now what I am confused with is that isnt $p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f})$ supposed to give us the predictive distribution $\bf{f_*}$ conditioned on the query point and posterior distribution $\bf{f}$? Here we already conditioned on posterior distribution $\bf{f}$ so why are we multiplying again with $p(\mathbf{f} \lvert \mathbf{X},\mathbf{y})$ and integrating?

What is "conceptual" difference between  $p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f})$ and $
p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{X},\mathbf{y})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual relationship by [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) is as follows:
$$p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{X},\mathbf{y}) 
= \int{p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f},\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{y})p(\mathbf{f} \lvert \mathbf{X},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{X_*})}\ d\mathbf{f}$$

It's just within this context, we have:

$$p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f},\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{y})=p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f})$$
because when you know $\mathbf{f}$, you won't need $\mathbf{X},\mathbf{y}$. Similarly, the second term reduces to $p(\mathbf{f|\mathbf{X},\mathbf{y}})$ since $\mathbf{f}$ is fed by $\mathbf{X,y}$, and having only $\mathbf{X}_*$ is not of any use.

Comment: +1 for explanation, I am still confused by the fact that why aren't we stopping at $p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f},\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{y})=p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f})$ and shouldnt posterior "not include" $\bf{X_*}$ term because we dont construct posterior by query points, we construct it from training points i.e. both $(\bf{X,y})$

Comment: also isnt $\mathbf{X},\mathbf{y}$  redundant here in $p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f},\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{y})$ , since $\bf{f}$ is based on $\mathbf{X},\mathbf{y}$

Comment: For your second comment: The relation between $\mathbf{f,X,y}$ is not deterministic, so $X,y$ are redundant because we only need $f$ to find $f_*$ from $X_*$. Otherwise $p(\mathbf{f|X,y})$ would be dirac delta.

Comment: What do you mean by stopping? We write law of total probability and remove redundant parts.

Comment: my apologies, the first comment had a typo. I meant , why arnt we stopping at $p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f},\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{y})$ as far as inference is concerned, why integrate with posterior $p(\mathbf{f} \lvert \mathbf{X},\mathbf{y})$ when the posterior is already present in $p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f},\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{y})$

Comment: so technically shouldnt $p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f},\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{y})$ be our inference of the value $\bf{f_*}$ given $\bf{X_*}$?

Comment: But, you don't know $f$, you only know the data, which is $X,y,X_*$. This is why you integrate wrt all possible $f$.

Comment: your first comment makes so much sense, if the relation between $\mathbf{f,X,y}$ deterministic, we could simply have written $p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f})$, since it is not deterministic we write $p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f},\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{y})$ right?

Comment: also technically based on your comment ``But, you don't know f, you only know the data, which is X,y,X∗. This is why you integrate wrt all possible f`` we are taking expected value of the $f_*$ with respect to all possible functions $f$ by integrating...right?

Comment: it is similar to that, we're considering all possible f, and find the distribution of $f_*$. A distribution gives you much more info than expectation.

Comment: the distribution part makes sense but doesnt integration give a definitive single answer?

Comment: No, the integration give you a function of $f_*,X_*,X_y$, not a single number because it's a distribution. Think about joint PDF integration for simplicity:$$f(x)=\int f(x,y)dy$$ Integral result is a function of $x$.

Comment: Perfect!! cant thank you enough!! I do have one tiny confusion on GP but I post it a another question, and hopefully can request for your contribution.

Comment: please take a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/448809/effect-of-covariance-kernel-on-random-variables-in-gaussian-process) if convenient